# completely delete sonar project

Tags: mysql, maven, sonarqube

I've deleted a sonar project from the web interface and re-executed an analysis with `mvn -U sonar:sonar` on another project at the next day as [this post](http://old.nabble.com/Incomplete-delete-of-a-project-td32021665.html#a32035998) said that sonar will automatically delete old data on the next analysis after 12 hours.

But it seems that the old data of the project that I deleted is still in the database. 
Does anyone has any idea about how to completely delete a sonar project?

Comment: Updated link to post: The relevant post is now at http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Incomplete-delete-of-a-project-td3182747.html